# Обмен информацией по USB

Tags: java, android

У меня следующая проблема - Настраиваю соединение по USB между терминалом и устройством android, соединение устанавливается если его настраивать через endPoints, однако так как у терминала только 1 EndPoint приходится использовать UsbSerial и вот с ним у меня возникает проблема.

`UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers()` возвращает -1, почему это происходит и что делать если не находится ни один драйвер?

```
// этот метод не находит драйверов
List<UsbSerialDriver> availableDrivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(usbManager); 

if (availableDrivers.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}

UsbSerialDriver driver = availableDrivers.get(0);
final UsbDeviceConnection connection2 = usbManager.openDevice(driver.getDevice());

if (connection == null) {
    // add UsbManager.requestPermission(driver.getDevice(), ..) handling here
    return;
}
```

Буду очень признателен если кто-то напишет или скинет ссылку на пример использования только 1 EndPoint для реализации обмена данными без UsbSerial

Comment: Работай через эндпоинты) по крайней мере есть один вход один выход

Comment: @eri поправьте меня если я ошибаюсь) Насколько я понял если всего 1 endPoint то невозможно настроить обмен информацией без использования UsbSerial

Comment: Usbserial это простейшая обертка над эндпоинтом.

Comment: @eri Тогда буду пробовать без неё, спасибо!)

Comment: Проблему решил приняв совет eri

Answer (score 1):

Эндпоинты это основа обмена по USB. Дальше обмен осуществляется либо через драйвер, который подключается к эндпоинтам и выдает устройство в диспечере устройств / devfs. Либо напрямую через `libusb`. При подключении через последний драйвер выгружается.

USBserial это простейший драйвер, который создает виртуальный ком порт и связывает его с усб устройством. Драйверу нужно знать какие устройства поддерживаются и если устройства нет в списке - подключиться к нему через ком порт можно только насильно. Но и если всё хорошо, то libusb также может отнять устройство у драйвера.

USBserial помогает с контролем потока данных, на нем можно гонять прямую передачу файлов через ядро. Также удобен для работы с консольными программами или с теми, где в настройках указывается устройство вручную пользователем.

Работа через эндпоинт проще в програмном режиме. Не стоит пинать устройство ннасильно, если оно не поддерживается потому как это требует привелегий и не надежно при переносе на другую систему или другое устройство.